# how do I add preventDefault() backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I add preventDefault()  to the `<button>` in the event?  What I have below is not working .. thanks

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        //console.log('initializing ' + this.options.blankOption);
        this.template = $('#list-template').children();
    },
    el: '#container',
    events: {
        'click button' : 'render'
    },
    render: function(){

        this.events.preventDefault(); // not working ????

        var data = this.model.get('data');

        $.each(data,function (i,v) {
            console.log(data.text + " " + data.href);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

this.events is not a event object. so it not work

try this:

```
render: function(event){
    event && event.preventDefault();

    var data = this.model.get('data');

    $.each(data,function (i,v) {
        console.log(data.text + " " + data.href);
    });
}
```

Comment: It checks for the existence of event before invoking .preventDefault() on the event object. In this case its not necessary as all bound handlers receive the object when they are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Receive the event object as an argument

```
render: function(evt){

    evt.preventDefault();

    var data = this.model.get('data');

    $.each(data,function (i,v) {
        console.log(data.text + " " + data.href);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-activate the actions by adding

```
this.delegateEvents();  // Re-activates the events for all the buttons
```

If you add it to the render function of a backbone js view, then you can use event.preventDefault() as required.